# What is the significance of 22nd rajab in the history of Islam (Shia view)?

Tags: history, ritual, shiism

I have seen Shias celebrate the 22nd Rajab (the seventh Arabic lunar month) by making special cookies and sweet dishes, and by visiting each other.

What is the importance of 22nd Rajab in Islamic history?

What's the background of this day and why do Shias celebrate this day?

Comment: Are you sure it is 22nd of rajab? I've never heard of such thing.

Comment: yes it is 22nd rajab, its mostly celebrated in india and pakistan , i am not sure about other places

Answer (score 1):

I searched to some extent in regard to the importance of 22nd Rajab according to Shia view. I solely found a matter regarding this matter. Seemingly, at the above-mentioned day, Imam Jafar al Sadiq (peace be upon him) has done a miracle. It has mentioned it as Konday and likewise the miracle of Imam Sadiq (peace be upon him). (But to be honest, it was in Pakistani language, thus I was not able to figure out what it say). For further information, you'd better to the reference below if you are familiar with Pakistani.

**Reference**:

[http://islam.rosegalaxy.com](http://islam.rosegalaxy.com/islamic-months/22-rajab-konday-61/)

Comment: Just for info: Its Urdu

Comment: Uh, yeah, tis Urdu. God job mate for pointing out this point. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Kunde is celebrated by shia on 22nd  rajab  is an important day of the holy month dedicated to the 6th Imam Jafar-e-Sadiq. ... It is believed that if a person going through a worldly problem prays to Imam Jafar-e-Sadiq by making him the waseela (medium), God will definitely answer his/her prayers.

Answer (score 0):

I think this link explains the tradition of the Feast of Nazr on 22 Rajab beautifully. Although it is a social gathering, it is based on the concept of Islamic fulfilment through penance (Nazr), with references from the Qur'an and Ahadith. I think it's quite sad that the story regarding this beautiful tradition has not been passed down by parents to the younger generation.

[www.ezsoftech.com](http://www.ezsoftech.com/islamic/nazr.asp)

Comment: Hello and welcome to [islam.se]. This could be a good answer if you would provide more details on the practice instead of asking readers to check the link. Answer should be largely self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

My dear the Kundhe celebrated on 22 Rajab by Shias, which Sunni Muslims adopted to some extent. This fact has no references in Qur'an and Hadith. It is not celebrated because of any miracle or something. The fact of celebration is the death of Ameer Mawiya has made the Shia so happy that they wanted to celebrate and distribute sweets, but due to the fear of the kingdom, they celebrated the death behind closed doors. And still they do all this behind the doors, the announcements and invitations are not involved on this occasion, so this ritual has taken birth behind the doors and has been adopted by many without actual knowledge of Hadiths.

Answer (score 0):

It is an occasion for Shias to discuss Allah The Holy Quran and the Ahlul Bayt and to strengthen ties among the Islamic community with love and compassion. It is done openly and Nazri is shared with all. Related to times of Imam Jaffer Sadiq (a.s) whose 8000+ scholars included many scholars from other strands of Islam. Have a blessed month of Rajab

Answer (score 0):

Mavia died in the time of Imam Hussain(A.S) & 22 Rajab started during the time of Sixth Imam Jafar Al Saqique (A.S), he is great grand son of Imam Hussain(A.S).

Comment: We are not a site for argument and debate. Please focus on answering the question asked clearly, not on inserting tangential points or attacking other answers.